# Filling in a Gap in the Proof of the Converse to Modularity

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, abelian-varieties

Here is the theorem:

Let $f = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_nq^n \in S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$ be a newform with rational coefficients. Then there is a (unique up to $\mathbb Q$-isogeny) elliptic curve $E/\mathbb Q$ of conductor $N$ such that $f_E = f$, where $f_E := \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n(E)q^n$.

Milne's *Elliptic Curves*, page 222, gives the most detailed proof of this converse to the Modularity Theorem that I have seen. I have been able to fill in all of the details, except the general case. Namely, Milne specifies to the case where $E_f$, the canonical abelian variety attached to $f$ via the Shimura construction (which in this case is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$) is equal to $X_0(N)$. Then he gives a proof of the theorem using Eichler-Shimura, which I understand.

However, he ends with the following "proof" for the general case: "The proof of the general case is very similar except that, at various places in the argument, an elliptic curve has to be replace either by a curve or the Jacobian variety of a curve." No references or helpful additional details about what these mysterious curves are are given. Can someone either point me to a complete proof, or proof the general case from the special case here?

Comment: Doesn’t the book by Diamond and Shurman do this in detail?

Comment: IIRC the idea is that a rational modular form corresponds to a certain ideal $I$ of the Hecke algebra (generated by $T_n-a_n(f)$) acting on the Jacobian $J_0(N)$. The corresponding elliptic curve should be the quotient of $J_0(N)$ by the sum of the images of endomorphisms of $I$. But there are probably quite a few details to work out.

Comment: I don't think Diamond and Shurman does this; that text is concerned with Modularity and its equivalent versions. I still am looking for a reference that works all this out.

Comment: You can’t formulate Modularity at all without some sort of equivalent of this statement, so I’d still advise taking a good look at Diamond and Shurman (unless you tell me you’ve done it and found nothing).

Comment: I have read that entire text. I see Eichler-Shimura, but nowhere do I see how it is used to find an elliptic curve attached to a newform whose L-functions agree. I think, however, Knapp's book may cover this. I'll have to read more carefully tomorrow.

Comment: I’ve been able to look again at DS, and I think the book contains enough to prove the statement by combining the constructions of Section 6.6, the discussion about algebraization before Theorem 7.7.4, and Theorem 8.8.2 (possibly by tweaking its proof) – at least for existence, I think uniqueness uses a different set of tools.

Comment: I have since confirmed that Knapp covers all of this in explicit detail. By the way, matching up the L-functions at all factors requires Deligne-Langlands-Carayol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the argument I know. More precisely, I show that $f$ and the elliptic curve have the same $L$-function *up to finitely many factors*. If one accepts that the modular Jacobian $J_0(N)$ has good reduction outside $N$, these factors are only the primes dividing $N$. I don’t know how to deal with this final case – maybe Milne explains it – although I don’t think it’s the most significant part.

Let $T$ be the Hecke algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on modular forms for $\Gamma_0(N)$. We have a prime ideal $I_f \subset T$ such that $T_n-a_n(f) \in I$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $T/I_f \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Define $A_f=J_0(N)/I_fJ_0(N)$. By the discussion of Diamond and Shurman in Section 6.6, $A_f$ is a rational elliptic curve.

Moreover, if $p$ does not divide $N$ and is of good reduction for $A_f$ (the second condition is redundant, but excludes only a finite number of primes anyway), then $T_p$ acts on $A_f$ mod $p$ by $Frob_p+Ver_p$ by Eichler-Shimura.

In particular, if $\ell \neq p$ is any prime, as the reduction mod $p$ is an isomorphism for the $\ell^n$-torsion points, it follows that $T_p$ acts on $A_f[\ell^n]$ by $Frob_p+Ver_p$. Since $A_f$ is an elliptic curve, we know that on $T_{\ell}A_f$, $Frob_p+Ver_p$ acts by $a_p(A_f)$.

But by definition, $T_p$ acts on $A_f$ by $a_p(f)$, so that $a_p(f)=a_p(A_f)$, QED.